# removing unity and gnome panel in xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

After running the update manager for the first time and rebooting, I am greeted with a few ubuntu applications and when I logout I can see the unity and gnome shell option in the login screen.

How can I remove unity and gnome panel without breaking xubuntu-desktop?

I want to completely remove the non-XFCE options from the login manager e.g. lightdm/gdm.

Comment: I'm using xfce now. I mean when I logout to the Desktop Manager I can select Ubuntu,Ubuntu2D,Gnome shell. I want to remove them without breaking xubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion, the **best** way to do that is install from xubuntu media instead of ubuntu mainline media and installing the xubuntu-desktop package.  In my experience, removing the packages you're talking about leads to broken dependency chains or weird bugs when you try and get some other app/widget to work.  You can certainly do it, but I'm not a fan of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexfce) for information on getting a 'pure' xfce.